# Creating SQL translations for EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` with EF Core is a great way to write more complex queries and also keep boilerplate down by doing binding on the fly with string interpolation too. A common clause we use in our code base is the `IN` clause.

Unfortunately when using `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` this is not possible because the "translation"/mapping to SQL is not implemented (FYI we are using the Pomelo library).

Here is an example:

```
var rowsChanged = await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync($@"
    UPDATE 
        ExampleTable
    SET
        ExampleColumn = true,
    WHERE
        Id IN ({ids})
");
```

This results in an error

> System.InvalidOperationException : The current provider doesn't have a store type mapping for properties of type 'int[]'

To get around this, we build a custom query string and use the non-interpolated alternative, while this may still look clean it gets very messy in even a mildly complex query.

```
var idPlaceholders = Enumerable.Range(0, ids.Length).Select(i => $"{{{i}}}").StringJoin(", ");

var query = $@"
    UPDATE 
        ExampleTable
    SET
        ExampleColumn = true,
    WHERE
        Id IN ({idPlaceholders})
";

var rowsChanged = await dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(query, ids);
```

I tried doing this in DbContext `ConfigureConventions`, but I get the same error, it must be at a different level.

```
configurationBuilder
    .DefaultTypeMapping<int[]>()
    .HasConversion<IntArrayDbValueConverter>();

configurationBuilder
    .Properties<int[]>()
    .HaveConversion<IntArrayDbValueConverter>();
```

There must be some way to add a custom "translation" to the `DbContext` or provider. Any of the scarce documentation I can find on this topic has been vague or irrelevant. Looking for help.

Comment: The `.ExecuteSql...` methods can take a TVP `SqlParameter` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks for the info, unfortunately this looks like it is not supported in MySQL (which is unfortunately what I am using)

Comment: The interpolated parts must represent valid SQL parameters as you would supply them to a SQL string executed by ADO.Net.

Comment: @GertArnold I see what you mean, parameters must be "primitives" as a sort, that makes sense, but if there is a way to make our lives easier by expanding a list of primitives I would love to try it.